# How to configure email on spree commerce

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, spree

I am new to Spree Commerce and have been trying to develop a store front. I want to have the "Forgot Password" functionality working, which sends email to the user. I have successfully installed the gem "spree_mail settings". I am able to see it in admin interface. I am not sure about three things:

1. What should be the right settings in the admin interface. (I would like the email to be going out from public email server like gmail.)
2. Do i need to configure anything other than the the ones in Admin > Configurations section.
3. Do i need to install (or uninstall if already present) things like SendMail PostFix.

P.S. i am running this on Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM.

Comment: I would recommend removing spree_mail_settings and configuring all your mail settings through ActionMailer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration You can configure things to use postfix, sendmail, smtp, or anything else supported by ActionMailer.

Comment: Thanks gmacdougall. I was considering that option but only as the last one. spree_mail_settings is an active extension. so if possible, i would not like to reinvent the wheel and also maintain it. But thanks for it. If i don't hear any thing else soon, i would go with your suggestion..

Comment: ActionMailer is well supported and easy to configure. spree_mail_settings used to be integrated in to Spree, but it had many issues and gotchas which caused problems. It was removed from spree, and moved to the extension in order to provide legacy support for people who used it. I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks. Then ActionMailer it is.